# Mysterious Repetition of Text in String

Tags: trigger, class, string, loop

On a BeforeInsert and BeforeUpdate, per lead in a list, this code section loops through a map.  Every time a value in the map matches some value on the lead, text is added to a string, including information pulled in with that value.  After looping through the map, a field on the lead is updated with the final string.

This is the problem:

- On a single insert, the field inexplicably repeats text.
- On a single update, the field inexplicably repeats text.
- On a mass insert, the field only on the last *lead* repeats text.

For example:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
for(Lead l : changedRecords){
        String disqAccs = '';
        Integer x = 1;
        for(Account val : leadDisqAccountsMap.values() ){  
            if(val.Name == l.FirstName+' '+l.LastName || val.Name == l.Company){
                System.debug(val.Name);
                disqAccs = disqAccs + 'Account '+x++ +':' + '\n' + 
                           'Name = '+val.Name+ '\n' + 
                           'Account Status = '+val.Account_Status__c+ '\n' + 
                           'Link = https://cs77.salesforce.com/'+val.Id+ '\n'; 

                l.Suspect_Accounts__c = disqAccs;
            }       
        }                   
    }
```

Any ideas about the cause in my code and how to fix it?

FYI:

Here's the debug log at `System.debug(val.Name);`

[image]

Comment: Most likely the double loop but would need to see rest of code.....How you set up your collections may matter here

Comment: What is the structure of `leadDisqAccountsMap`?  Do you have duplicate leads in `changedRecords` or duplicate accounts in `leadDisqAccountsMap`?  You need more debug statements to show the lead  values and the account values as you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clues Eric and David; the problem *was* in my map.  Having earlier added the contents of another map to `leadDisqAccountsMap`, I did end up with duplicate accounts.  So I made the changes below.

Before:

```
        Map<String, Account> leadDisqAccountsMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        Map<String, Account> leadDisqAccountsStreetMap = new Map<String, Account>();                                    
        if( !leadDisqAccounts.isEmpty() ){
            for(Account leadDisqAccount : leadDisqAccounts){
                leadDisqAccountsMap.put(leadDisqAccount.Name, leadDisqAccount);
                leadDisqAccountsStreetMap.put(leadDisqAccount.BillingStreet, leadDisqAccount);
            }        
        }

        leadDisqAccountsMap.putAll(leadDisqAccountsStreetMap);
```

After:

```
        Map<String, Account> leadDisqAccountsMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        Map<String, Account> leadDisqAccountsStreetMap = new Map<String, Account>();                                    
        if( !leadDisqAccounts.isEmpty() ){
            for(Account leadDisqAccount : leadDisqAccounts){
                leadDisqAccountsMap.put(leadDisqAccount.Name, leadDisqAccount);
                if(leadDisqAccount.BillingStreet != null){  
                    leadDisqAccountsStreetMap.put(leadDisqAccount.BillingStreet, leadDisqAccount);
                }        
            }        
        }

        if( !leadDisqAccountsStreetMap.isEmpty() ){
            leadDisqAccountsMap.putAll(leadDisqAccountsStreetMap);
        }
```

That'll help when account's billing streets are null, but if a lead's name matches an account's name *and* its street matches the account's street, I'll get repeated text in the string.  I think I can live with that.